# Magento 2 Luma Product Detailed Page resize

Tags: magento2

Hy,

how can i resize the Magento 2 Luma Product Detailed Page and insert a second "New Block" on the right side like this printscreen?

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i dont know how can i do that, where is the code for the detailed page or how can i made the product main info longer oder the detailed page? Do you see my printscreen? Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Detailed product page sources is in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/product`
Create you own Theme. 
There is [documentation and developer guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html). In your Theme folder create Magento_Catalog folder, where you can rewrite original .phtml's, that you need to rewrite.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have created template already, now i have created the Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and the Magento_Catalog/template/product/view/newblock.phtml
Can you help me to past the correct code for my wish?